# Should virtual host files contain two <directory> directives?

Tags: security, apache-virtualhost

We've heard that a good security practice is to reset everything in the virtual host to allow nothing, then have another directive to allow specific access - something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html

  <Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow 
    Deny from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/example/public_html >
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It sort of makes sense but we're unsure so would love a few opinions on the best way to set things up.

Comment: Can you please cite these sources?

Comment: Don't remember sorry - our virtual host files have been setup like this for about 2 years and we don't have the original source links that lead us to do it this way. Nor can we find info about doing things this way so are re-evaluating the way we do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really use the `<Directory />` directive as written there, you aren't changing anything for that virtual host, but instead you're declaring the same overrides over and over again for the directory `/`.

So those options did nothing, or in the best case, only the last `<Directory />` section encountered was be applied:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging

If that section looks the same for every virtual host, that won't cause problems, but if some virtual hosts differ and the number of virtual hosts changes over time, it will be confusing to figure out which one's `<Directory />` directive was applied.

I would remove the `<Directory />` section from all virtual hosts and declare it once, in a global configuration.

Comment: That's what we suspected - thanks heaps for clearing that up. Cheers